# Riptides caused by satellite pull

Tags: gravity, tides

How many moons would be required to induce almost continual tidal pull to create a near constant tidal riptides?

Comment: Tides are big and affect a huge area.  Ours are caused by the moon.  Riptides or [rip currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_current) are small and locallized and have to do with landforms and water movement at a given shore.  The moon does not affect those as far as I know.

Comment: Uh, we already have continuous tides. "Slack" tides are only a brief period when the flow reverse direction; the process doesn't really stop. What were you really wanting here?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE Laird Bruce Boughner, glad you found us.  We have a [tour] and [help] you might wish to check out.

Answer (score 3):

Forces are vectorial, meaning they have a direction. Equal forces with opposite directions nullify each other.

Many moons won't generate bigger tides, rather flimsy ones, for the most of the time, since their pull will be having different directions.

If you want to have big tides, 1 moon is sufficient.